# Different value appears when updating field with $set

Tags: mongodb

I was trying to update one field in database and got very confusing result:

look at the field 'zipcode'
before it was:

```
''
```

after

```
1153
```

However I tryed to put different value

```
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51265a5ebdbff320f02007a4"), "region_code" : "NY", "region_name" : "New York", "secret_answer2" : "Mercedes", "l_name" : "Gonzalez", "f_name" : "Zachary", "month" : 5, "country_name" : "United States", "country_code" : "US", "year" : 1970, "password" : "xxxxxx", "day" : 2, "metrocode" : "501", "city" : "New York", "secret_answer" : "xxxxxx", "zipcode" : "", "longitude" : xxxxxxx, "areacode" : "212", "ip" : "xxxxxxx", "latitude" : xxxxxx }
> db.users.update({_id: ObjectId("51265a5ebdbff320f02007a4")}, {$set: {zipcode:02201} } )
> db.users.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51265a5ebdbff320f02007a4"), "region_code" : "NY", "region_name" : "New York", "secret_answer2" : "Mercedes", "l_name" : "Gonzalez", "f_name" : "Zachary", "month" : 5, "country_name" : "United States", "country_code" : "US", "year" : 1970, "password" : "xxxxxx", "day" : 2, "metrocode" : "501", "city" : "New York", "secret_answer" : "xxxxxx", "zipcode" : 1153, "longitude" : xxxxxxx, "areacode" : "212", "ip" : "xxxxxxx", "latitude" : xxxxxx }
```

## updated:

```
> db.users.find({},{zipcode:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51265a5ebdbff320f02007a4"), "zipcode" : 1153 }
> db.users.update({_id:ObjectId("51265a5ebdbff320f02007a4")}, {$set:{zipcode:02201}})
> db.users.find({},{zipcode:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51265a5ebdbff320f02007a4"), "zipcode" : 1153 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, numbers beginning with a 0 are interpreted as octal.

So either store your `zipcode` values as strings:

```
{$set: {zipcode: '02201'}}
```

or use a decimal value:

```
{$set: {zipcode: 2201}}
```